# Fabric.js: clone loaded svg

Tags: svg, fabricjs

This might be very basic, but I am new to Fabric.js. I cannot clone a loaded svg like this:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.loadSVGFromURL('/test/fabric/sphere.svg', function(objects, options) {
    var sphere1 = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    sphere1.set({left: 100, top: 100 });
    canvas.add(sphere1).renderAll();
});
var sphere2=fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.sphere1);
sphere2.set({ left: 200, top: 150 });   
canvas.add(sphere2).renderAll();
```

Also instanciating sphere2 like below did not work:

```
var sphere2=fabric.util.object.clone(canvas.getActiveObject());
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples over [here helped](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2598) me out. It appeared that you have to define a group first.